# Webpack, babelrc dynamic import not working

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack-4, es6-modules, chunks, dynamic-import

I spent quite some time trying to figure this out myself but here I am, with no more options to consider than to reach out to the community for some guidance.

I am trying to do something very simple in principle, dynamically import a component with WebPack, using ES6 modules and babelrc.

I have the following app architecture:

> -root
>
> -- root/.webpack.dev.js
>
> -- root/.webpack.prod.js
>
> -- root/.babelrc
>
> -- root/package.json
>
> -- root/node_modules/
>
> -- root/dist/
>
> -- root/src/
>
> --- root/src/index.js
>
> --- root/src/modules/
>
> --- root/src/modules/module1.js
>
> --- root/src/modules/module2.js
>
> --- root/src/modules/module3.js
>
> --- root/src/modules/module4.js
>
> --- root/src/modules/module5.js

In my module1.js (not the real name) I am using the following code to dynamically import module2.js:

```
  async function load(configObject) {
  const {
      init,
      requestPermissions
  } = await import( /* webpackChunkName: "chunkname" */ `./module2.js`)
  init(configObject)
  _namespace.requestPermissions = requestPermissions;
```

}

My .babelrc file:

```
   {
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead"
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],
  ],
  "comments": true
}

// "@babel/preset-env"
```

My Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const {
  InjectManifest
} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    lib: "./src/index.js"
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [{
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      parallel: true,
      cache: true,
      terserOptions: {
        ecma: 8,
        warnings: false,
        parse: {
          ecma: 8,
        },
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
          comparisons: false,
        },
        mangle: {
          safari10: true,
        }, 
        module: false,
        output: {
          ecma: 5,
          comments: false,
          ascii_only: true,
        },
        toplevel: false,
        nameCache: null,
        ie8: false,
        keep_classnames: undefined,
        keep_fnames: false,
        safari10: false,
      },
    })],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "dist",
    compress: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    },
    overlay: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
        'API_URL': JSON.stringify('ENDPOINT')

      }
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      generateStatsFile: true
    }),
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      "swDest": "firebase-messaging-sw.js",
    }),
    new InjectManifest({
      "swSrc": path.join('src', 'firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    })
  ]
};
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "refactor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "backuprefacto.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config=webpack.prod.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config=webpack.dev.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-minify": "^0.5.1",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

I have checked all my modules, none of them expect for module1.js are calling module2.js.
I have also explored the option of webpack comments being deleted by babel and therefore added a comments: true to make sure the webpackChunkName is not being deleted but in the end, the only thing that gets built is my lib.js, not the lib.bundle.js that I expect.

I have also tried to remove all the TerserPlugin bit to check if that could have the same impact but nothing changed there.

In the need, what I am looking for is simply to have the module2.js loaded whenever it is invoked, and I therefore expect a new network request to materialise this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that if you want to use dynamic imports you need to make sure first that you are not importing at all the module at the top....

In module1.js I was importing twice, once at the top, the "regular way", once the dynamic way which was obviously leading to module2.js being consistently loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem by modify .babelrc, modules: false

```js
["@babel/preset-env", {
        "loose": true,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3,
        "modules": false
      }],
```